# Arduino can't see any library I have installed for nrf905?

Tags: library, nrf24l01+, wireless

nrf905\ 
nRF905-All-In-One-Shield\
RadioHead-master\
RadioHead\

None any of them are compiled with their examples without getting errors.

*Error message:*

```
nRF905_RX.ino:4:20: fatal error: NRF905.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Error compiling.
```

Libraries used:

[Elechouse](http://www.github.com/elechouse/nRF905)
[RadioHead Github](http://www.github.com/PaulStoffregen/RadioHead)
[RadioHead Doxygen](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead)
[zkemble/nRF905](http://www.github.com/zkemble/nRF905)

Comment: Which Arduino? What version of the IDE? Where did you get those libraries from? (link). What error messages? Try to give a bit more detail.

Comment: actally I have the same problem in 1.5.2 and 1.6.5 
the links are : https://github.com/elechouse/nRF905
https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/RadioHead
http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/
https://github.com/zkemble/nRF905
I intend to connect it with arduino uno when the code will be verified  correctly .

Comment: the error message is : NRF905.h : No such file or directory compilation terminated

Comment: @SalamEtaiwi - where have you put the libraries?

Comment: in the libraries folder at arduino  folder  that I use

Comment: no error when using examples of this library "RadioHead"  after added it to the library folder , but when trying of another examples there are  errors .

Comment: @SalamEtaiwi - I have tried to compile the one from elechouse and that one gives continuous errors, even if the ide is given the exact location, it will throw more errors. If the radiohead one works why not just use it?

Comment: @RSM I will try it , I just was confused why not  all  of them work right ! 
thanks for reply

Comment: @SalamEtaiwi - I have just got the zkemble one to compile, which didn't before.

Comment: @RSM so is there  error ?

Comment: I am writing an answer to explain as  I have all the libraries compiling

Comment: about zkemble one after I add the library I  create a new folder called "src" and place the .cpp and .h files into the new folder . as he explain when I emailed him . but still have problem with "nRF905_config.h" it appears now in the error message

Comment: I shall explain the problem in the answer as I also tried that and the same result happened

Comment: thanks for continuity in this ,, 
for correction I used 1.5.8 and 1.6.5 not 1.5.2

Comment: @Salam - Let us know if you get it working ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you were getting when you compiled was because if the libraries were extracted straight to the Arduino library folder from the .zip, the file path becomes too long for the compiler to find it.

So what you need to do is to create a new folder in the libraries folder for each library.

**Note**: you cannot do the standard `libraryName\src\foo.cpp` as this seems to give errors for these libraries (in that it does not find them).

What you need to do is to make a file in the `libraries` directory; for the *zkemble* one you can create a main folder called `nRF905`, then take the files under `nRF905/arduino/nRF905` from github and place them in the folder created earlier. It should look like this: 
[image]

You should repeat this for the Elechouse one as well as it solved the problem too. i.e.

- `C:\\...\libraries\NRF\examples\`
- `C:\\...\libraries\NRF\NRF905.cpp`
- `C:\\...\libraries\NRF\NRF905.h`
- `C:\\...\libraries\NRF\keywords.txt`

Also of importance is that once you have the library from Elechouse compiling you need to open up the .cpp file and go to line 16, where there is

```
PROGMEM unsigned int freq_tab[10] = {
```

and to this add `const`, like so:

```
PROGMEM const unsigned int freq_tab[10] = {
```

Comment: thanks alot I did what you said ,actually most of the examples give no errors , but there are others give anyway I am now satisfy with this and I tried with a couple of a code (transmitte and recieve ) no errers was in transmite one and the serial monitor showed the right things but the problem was in the recieving side , the Rx led didnt lighting on ’ and not any data in the serial monitor. these are the codes ( transmitte , recieve):

Comment: sorry , it cant be sending , but they are the examples from "RadioHead" library ,, nrf905_client ,,, nrf905_server ...

Comment: @Salam - first off, glad it worked.  I would recommend posting a new question here. And then I would recommend you open an issue on the RadioHead github page so you can bring it to the attention of the libraries author, he might also be able to give you a accurate answer. I am also on a phone at the moment so can't do much.

Comment: I will do that in sha`a Allah .. thanks again ^^